Utf8Json serializer custom formatter not working
I want to make custom formatter for utf8json serializer. Functionality is that if string property has value "null" it should deserialize it as null. And formatter should be enabled globally so i do not have to call it on every deserialization.
example message:
{
  "connectorId": 1,
  "status": "Available",
  "errorCode": "NoError",
  "info": "null",
  "timestamp": "2024-05-16T09:17:13Z",
  "vendorId": "",
  "vendorErrorCode": ""
}

property "info" with value "null" should be deserialized as null not as "null".
Utf8Json serializato library link:
https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json
So i made an custom formatter that looks like this:
public class NullStringJsonFormatter : IJsonFormatter<string>
{
    public void Serialize(ref JsonWriter writer, string value, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
    {
        writer.WriteString(value);
    }

    public string Deserialize(ref JsonReader reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
    {
        if (reader.GetCurrentJsonToken() == JsonToken.String)
        {
            var value = reader.ReadString();
            if (value == "null")
            {
                return null;
            }
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

and it works when i put annotation:
[JsonFormatter(typeof(NullStringJsonFormatter))]
on every property that should be deserialized like that.
But i wanted it to be globally because i have more that 100 models, so i made an Composite resolver in startup.cs
            CompositeResolver.RegisterAndSetAsDefault( new IJsonFormatter[]
            {
                new NullStringJsonFormatter()
            },
                new []
                {
                    StandardResolver.ExcludeNull
                });


Functionality for exclude null (StandardResolver.ExcludeNull) works fine but "null" is still deserialized as "null" so formatter do not work.
So my question would be how to make NullStringJsonFormatter work globally without need to annotate every property?

Fix the bug in the JSON generator instead of trying to cover it up. These unlucky people have names that break computers. Null Family History.  We have an employee named Null

If there's no info, either omit the field or properly set it to null: "field" : null. The library you tried to use was abandoned 6 years ago too. System.Text.Json works with UTF8 and is faster than almost all of the serializers released 6 years ago.

I am getting that "null" from a device (Charger for EV) so i cannot seti it to null. Well last thing to do is to change to the System.Text I would prefer to find solution with existing serializator.

Is it possible to change to the System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?

It is possible but I would rather solve it with existing serializer, change to System.Text is my last option.
